# SQL Sub Query JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have the following tables

```
Table 'Flight' (
number int,
dest VARCHAR(4),
arrTime Date,
Foreign Key(dest) references Airport(code)
)
```

and

```
Table 'Airport' (
code VARCHAR(4),
PRIMARY KEY(code)
)
```

Lets say i have the following data for Flight

```
'Flight'
 2,'TX','10/5/2015 1:32'
 3,'NY','10/5/2015 4:20'
 1,'TX','10/5/2015 1:20'
 4,'NY','10/5/2015 4:21'
```

and for Airport

```
'TX'
'NY'
```

For each Airport i want to retrieve all Flight Numbers that arrive consecutively at the Airport so it would pretty much look like the data i provided for the flight table. Im working on a sub query to do this but i cant get the desired output...

```
 1,'TX','10/5/2015 1:20'
 2,'TX','10/5/2015 1:32'
 3,'NY','10/5/2015 4:20'
 4,'NY','10/5/2015 4:21'
```

i have tried the following but i just cant get the correct output

```
SELECT Airport.code, Timez
FROM Flight JOIN Airport
ON Flight.dest = Airport.code
ORDER BY DATE(arrTime) DESC as Timez
```

help would be appreciated

Comment: Order by airport then by arriveTime.

so it would look like:
    ORDER  BY Airport.code, arrTime

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY Airport.code, Flight.arrTime`.

This sorts all the flights for the same airport together, and then orders them by time within those groups.

Don't use `DESC`, that will put them in reverse time order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this to get the output you indicate:

```
SELECT Flight.number n, Airport.code c, Flight.arrTime t
   FROM Flight JOIN Airport
   ON Flight.dest = Airport.code
   ORDER BY c, t DESC
```

No need to convert the `arrTime` field as it's already at DATE.

Howerver, you won't get the full date and time as the `arrTime` field of DATE format doesn't keep that info.  You'd need a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP field for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Airport.code, Flight.arrTime 
FROM Flight JOIN Airport
ON Flight.dest = Airport.code
ORDER BY Airport.code, Flight.arrTime ASC